# Java fixed field file format

Tags: java, ascii, marshalling, field, fixed

I would like to know if exists something like JAXB for **fixed field ascii text format**.
Can be very useful to Marshal java objects to fixed field ascii text file like JAXB do with XML.

Thank you.

Comment: This can be? http://fixedformat4j.ancientprogramming.com/usage/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, i think it is exactly what i needed. Please mind that needs commons-lang but not last version, i had to use legacy v.2.6 otherwise i got a StringUtils not found.

http://fixedformat4j.ancientprogramming.com/usage/index.html